# Rails 6 e-wallet db setup of Transaction model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find good example of e-wallet setup from scratch in Rails that's why I'm asking the question here. I have two models `Wallet` and `Transaction`. The first one allows me to store information about the available balance and the second one should keep track of all incoming and outgoing transactions from the wallet.

```
# models/transaction.rb

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wallet

  validates :wallet, :transaction_type, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true
end

# models/wallet.rb

class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :transactions
end
```

Everything works except tracking transactions between wallets i.e. I would like to be able to track which wallet the money was sent to. How to do it?

Comment: I have added an answer but there may be some information missing from your question, are you only handling transactions between wallets?

Comment: @Claeusdev I should keep track of all wallet transactions. This could also mean deposits and withdrawals not just between wallets (e.g. deposits/withdrawals from external services not between wallets).

Comment: Okay, then in  that case, lemme update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your current model structure and what you're trying to achieve, I do think you're on the right path. Just a few things you could do.

In your transaction model you can add `to_wallet` thus the wallet the transaction is moving from and the `from_wallet` the wallet the transaction was initiated.:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :to_wallet, class_name: "Wallet"
  belongs_to :from_wallet, class_name: "Wallet"

  validates :transaction_type, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true
end
```

Then you can run a migration to add `to_wallet_id` and `from_wallet_id` to your `Transaction` model. Active Record is smart enough to parse these ids to the `Transaction` model to get the correct transaction object.

Comment: I need `from_wallet` to be optional. How the migration should looks like?

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, you could just pass `belongs_to :from_wallet, optional: true`. This should make it work without any need for migration.

Comment: Naah I've an error when I tried to create a new Transaction record `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'to_wallet_id' for Transaction.)` which means I have to have `to_wallet_id` field in my db

Comment: oh that's what you mean. uhmm lemme try to add more stuff to the answer but you could just add a migration for `to_wallet_id` as integer and `from_wallet_id` as integer as well.

Comment: But those will be just an integers, I want to pass an object of `Wallet` there

Comment: the `class_name: "Wallet"` inside the model will get the object for you. it'll look on the `wallets` table and find the wallet with id of `to_wallet_id`. I am also updating my answer.

Comment: I can't use STI - it's really, really trouble maker. If I add `to_wallet_id` and `from_wallet_id` and wants to create a new record: `Transaction.create!(from_wallet_id: Wallet.first.id, to_wallet_id: Wallet.last.id, amount: 123, transaction_type: 0)` I'm getting an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method wallet for #<Transaction:0x00007fd7e87bfe90>)
Did you mean?  wallet_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235782/discussion-between-claeusdev-and-mr-muscle).